# StarSchema - Entity Framework Core - Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-relationship, data-warehouse, star-schema

I am trying to build a datawarehouse (DWH), using the code-first approach (star-schema):

Fact-/dimension classes:

```
    [Table("FactBase")]
    public class FactBase
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DimTest1")]
        public string DimDigitalesBuchISBN { get; set; }

        public virtual DimTest1 DimTest1 { get; set; }  
    }


    [Table("DimTest1")]
    public class DimTest1
    {
        [Key]
        public string ISBN { get; set; }

        public string Bla { get; set; }
    }
```

Context:

```
public class XDBContextDWH : DbContext
{      
    public DbSet<FactBase> FactBase { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DimTest1> DimTest1 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(new string("connection string"));
    }
}
```

After using migration the schema looks like this:

[image: Here]

Based on that [star schema](https://www.etl-tools.com/images/Articles/Star%20Schema.png), shouldn't be the relationship (here: [SQL](https://justpaste.it/8w9tk)) like that?

[image: here]

Comment: updated my post, thanks to @Ortiga

Comment: Why would you want to build a OLAP schema in EF?  Star schemas are not appropriate for an OLTP source.  Instead, you should use 3NF(+) for an application data store.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the attribute `[ForeignKey("DimTest1")]`, you're telling EF to use `DimTest1` as the navigation property of the `FactBase` class, not pointing to the `DimTest1` class.

But since that property does not exist, it does not create the relationship.

Change your class to:

```
[Table("FactBase")]
public class FactBase
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DimTest1")]
    public string DimDigitalesBuchISBN { get; set; }
    public virtual DimTest1 DimTest1 { get; set; } // navigation property
}
```

This should make it work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

As you imply is your question, the star schema Fact table should use a composite key made up of the foreign keys it's referencing.
So I would say there are a couple issues with your situation that should be addressed.
First, a fact table probably shouldn't have a a column called Id, though it's not really going to hurt anything, it probably wouldn't ever be used to query by, so you are just adding extra data taking up disk space.
Second, and probably the answer you are looking for is, if you want a composite primary key on your fact table, you need to specify that in the Database Context.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<FactBase>()
        .HasKey(x => new { x.Id, x.DimDigitalesBuchISBN });
}
```

As I mentioned, you probably don't want to include the Fact.Id column in your PK but instead you would refer to more than one dimension like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<FactBase>()
        .HasKey(x => new { x.Dim1Id, x.Dim2Id, x.Dim3Id});
}
```

Where Dim1Id, Dim2Id and Dim3Id are the primary keys of your dimensions.
I should also mention that you need to remove the [Key] attribute from the Id field of your FactBase class.

refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations